# AdView not recognized in Android Studio

Tags: android, admob, adview

I am trying to integrate Admob in my App, but Android Studio can't find those libraries:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

This is my top-level gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

And this project-level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tomhogenkamp.personalcalc"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have added Admob in more apps, but I had no troubles with this.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the dependency for ads. Your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
  compile 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
}
```

should have an additional line:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
  compile 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
}
```

For more info, we recently wrote a [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/importing-mobile-ads-sdk-with-firebase.html) about the ways to import the Mobile Ads SDK with Firebase. There's also an [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qCxo0D-Sak&index=6&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKX0pUJV3uqp6N3NeHwHh0c) of the Mobile Ads Garage that covers this.

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager - > Extras - > Install Google Repositories & Google Play Services

If you have already updated these, share error log displaying exact error

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the google play service is properly installed

Open SDK manager and install google play service.

then add this line to the Gradle (Module)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```